# Memory Reference Sent to Double Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

So I'm looking for clarification on something that works. I'm pretty sure I understand what is happening but wanted to be sure before proceeding with my work.

I have a function defined as follows:

```
name* createName(char* firstName, char* lastName)
{
    name* newName = (name*)malloc(sizeof(name));

    initStringValue(&newName->firstName, firstName);
    initStringValue(&newName->lastName, lastName);

    newName->firstNameSize = strlen(newName->firstName);
    newName->lastNameSize = strlen(newName->lastName);

    return newName;
}
```

The structure "name" is defined like so:

```
struct name 
{
    char* firstName;
    char* lastName;

    int firstNameSize;
    int lastNameSize;
};
```

Another function responsible for the copy of the name strings is written like the following:

```
void initStringValue(char** destination, char* source)
{
    int length = strlen(source) + 1;
    int size = length * sizeof(char);
    *destination = (char*)malloc(size);
    memset(*destination, 0, size);
    strcpy(*destination, source);
}
```

If I'm understanding what I've done here, by using the & operator I've signified that I wish to send not a value but its associated memory address. In a statement such as

```
&newName->firstName
```

where the struct member firstName is a char* I've indicated that I would like to send the memory address of this pointer and not the pointers value (which happens to be a memory address in and of itself). The -> operator dereferences this pointer to the member of the pointer but then the & operator essentially returns us to the firstName memory reference instead, allowing me to manipulate information at that memory reference.

Now things get wild (for me anyway). To actually work with that memory reference, I end up using double indirection (so very passive aggressive). As it follows a memory reference (like that of &newName->firstName) sent to a char** like that of char** destination in the initStringValue function, would be a pointer of a pointer where the latter is assigned the memory reference returned by &newName->firstName. By then using *destination I'm working with a pointer pointed to the memory reference of &newName->firstName. Or stated differently, a pointer whose first and only member is the memory reference of newName->firstName.

Am I actually understanding this correctly?

Comment: First of all please don't use language-tags that are not relevant. If you're programming in C then use only that tag. Now for your question, what you are doing is emulating *call by reference*. If you search for `emulating call by reference in c` you should be getting plenty of hits.

Comment: Sounds as if you are right. When you want a function to change the value of a pointer, you have to give the function a pointer to that pointer. That's not different from any other types, e.g. if you want a function to change an `int` you need to pass a pointer to that `int`. Same thing. For pointers that means you'll end up with the pointer-to-pointer function parameter (aka **). Remember that a pointer variable just contains a value - just like any other variable.

Comment: There is no reason to do the `memset` in `initStringValue` then immediately overwrite the zeros.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for the clarification and pointing me (pun noticed but not avoided) in the right direction of call by reference. c++ has been removed from the language tags.

Comment: @Mike Notice that your code is not C, since there is no tag on your struct, and you write `name*`, and not `struct name*`.

Comment: @stark Thanks for the advice. I suppose setting the memory was an attempt to "zero terminate" the string but this is unnecessary? Possibly wasteful?

Comment: @user877329 What ? the typedef could be after. What ever I hate question C/C++ so yes let's say this is C++.

Comment: @Mike The `strcpy` will add the zero termination for you. The `memset` isn't needed.

Comment: @Stargateur How can I avoid the confusion as to whether or not I tag my question with c or c++ in the future?

Comment: @Mike Have you considered dropping the C-isms in the code and just use `std::string` and containers?  If you're developing a C++ application, there is no need to write code that looks like this in this day and age of C++.

Comment: @Mike Well, this is up to you, you should know what you use as language. This is simple do you use a c++ compiler or a c compiler ? Your file extension are .c or .cpp ? These two languages are really differents. Your question look like C code because you use function such as `malloc()` or `memset()` and you don't use `std::string` or `std::vector`. If you really code in C++, you have a very bad style.

Comment: @Mike - Parts of C and C++ are identical. Other part are nearly identical but have minor differences. Yet other part are extremely different. A C++ compiler can in many cases compile C code corretly. The posted code can be can be compiled with a C++ compiler but will fail to compile with a C compiler. Hence I assumed that you are using a C++ compiler.

Comment: @Stargateur Or you are doing some pointer exercises, in order to get a better understanding of how things work. Also, this name struct is likely to have different semantics from `std::string`. Since there is no capacity field, it is likely that it models immutable dynamic strings. However, the management of the pointer and size should be kept in a separate class.

Comment: @user877329 Are you sure that you want ping me with this comment ? I don't understand why you said me that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I actually understanding this correctly?

After reading your description, I'll say **yes**

I'll try to explain it with some examples.

If you do this:

```
void foo(int a)
{
    a = 5;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    foo(a);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

You'll get the output: `10`

That's because the function parameters are local variables to the function. In other words - any change made to a function parameter is lost when the function returns, i.e. the variable in `main` will not be changed.

If you want a function to change the value of a variable in `main` (aka in the caller), you'll have to pass a pointer. Like:

```
void foo(int* a)  // notice int*
{
    *a = 5;       // notice *a
}

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    foo(&a);       // notice &a
    printf("%d\n", a); 
    return 0;
}
```

This will output: `5`

This is a general rule regardless of the type. I used `int` in the example but it applies to any type - pointers as well.

So let's take an example with a pointer:

```
void foo(char** a, int size)    // notice char**
{
    *a = malloc(32);            // malloc memory
    strcpy(*a, "Hello world");  // copy some data into the memory
}

int main()
{
    char* a = NULL;   // a is not pointing to anything yet
    foo(&a);
    // Now a points to the malloc'ed memory
    printf("%s\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

This will output: `Hello world`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Glad to see that I'm on the right-ish path. I suppose I'll attempt to stick to c or c++ in the future as that seems to cause some confusion.